What is the recommended reference for modules on the schematics?
In my schematics I often use external modules like NFC readers, USB/TTL converters, MP3 players, and so on.
They are physically connected to the PCB with a connector (for example a standard 2,54 mm header or whatever) and they might be hosted on the board or placed externally.
For clarity, usually I draw my own symbol to represent the module itself and the meaning of its pins. On the BOM, I will have two entries: the actual module (with a note that is not soldered to the board) and the connector (that has to be soldered).
My question is: on the schematic, which reference should I use?
CN/J since the actual component is a connector, or IC/U since it represents the connection to a module?
UPDATE
Here an example of my own symbol for an NFC reader:

without it, here how it looks like:

This is a very simple example. For more complex modules, organizing pins (instead of having them in a row) is mode clear to read.

But if it's not on the PCB, but after a connector, your design should only have the connector, right? What purpose it has to have something on the PCB schematics as it's not part of that PCB but outside it?

@Justme, because (from my point of view) if I just place a connector the pins have no meaning. Just a row of signals without any function defined. It's hard to read such a schematic. Instead, a symbol allows me to place the pins in a more descriptive way. I'm going to add an example to the question.

Without an explanation, the downvotes only discourage to ask questions, since it does not provide a way to improve them

Make a schematic symbol for the connector, with names of the signals. That's how people make Ethernet and USB connectors for example.
And same goes for pin headers of Arduinos, ESP32 etc modules, regulator modules.
The benefit is that if you design both boards, you can define a single schematic component of a connector and use it on two projects.
But in general, what is usually done is that your schematic or PCB design just has a connector. The PCB manufacturer or PCB assembly house won't care about it. It's the next step in product assembly where you take Module A and Module B and plut them together.
So if you will use a NFC module, and if it is not soldered on at PCB assembly stage, it's not included as a component in BOM for PCB assembly manufacturing, the connector is, regardless of what it is for. If the NFC module will be soldered onto the PCB without connector, then the designator for module might be U.
So technically that's a higher level problem of handling the BOM for the product, not the PCB.
Of course if you are doing this only to yourself, you can do anything you like, it does not matter what something is called depending on if you solder on a connector or the actual module.

Ok, hence, the reference would be connector-like, as  J or CN, correct?

But your examples are connectors.

@Mark Yes, or X, or any other reference you use for connectors anyway. No my examples do include modules that attact via connectors.

@Mark Regarding my examples being conmectors is true in the sense that they are not modules - but the point is that when you draw an Ethernet or USB port, you generally don't just slab a schematic component of say a MagJack connector module with no other info than pin numbers, which will vary in function between manufacturers. You make a schematic component with the pin numbers and function ame for each pin, so you only need to look up pin name vs function once and then use the same MagJack in designs based on pin function names.
